# How to configure Docker mysql + aspnet

Tags: asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-for-windows

I have MySQL database and WebAPI project.
After installation of Docker for Windows. I can download image for MySQL in Linux mode, but when I try

```
docker pull microsoft/aspnet
```

it says

```
unknown blob
```

On the other side - in Windows containers mode. I can install aspnet, but when I try

```
docker pull mysql/mysql-server
```

it says

```
image for Linux
```

How I can combine both in single environment?

Answer (score 0):

At the Moment I would recommend using the aspnetcore container, since it uses Linux as a base and can be used with every other docker Container.
The amount of Windows-only Containers is limited, to say the least.

Comment: I have existing project in asp.net WebAPI and Windows Services and js ui. So it would be nice to combine them all in one.

Comment: I feel the pain too.. You will have then to build your own mysql Windows Container, it's porbably less work then Switch your codebase to aspnetcore